# Can I load mixed content Http and Https for Office 365 outlook addin?

Tags: ssl, office365api, office365-apps

As per below link,[security for Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/privacy-and-security) and what I understood that we need to apply SSL for Add-in and XYZ WEBAPP which we are expecting to get loaded inside the office 365 add-in task pane.

But, do next level WEBAPI calls also need to be secured (Https) which needed for XYZ application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, per documentation you refer to ...
"Data communicated with the web server that hosts a content, Outlook or task pane add-in as well as communication between the **add-in and any web services it uses** must be encrypted using the Secure Socket Layer (SSL) protocol."

Comment: Thank you Slava for the response. Does this mean not just the add-in and any web services it uses, but also any web services those web services use, and so on, ad infinitum? I'm trying to understand the reason for this and how to break the chain of HTTPS calls.

Comment: Requirement for HTTPS protocol as the following ... 1. Office app (ex. Outlook) to your add-in; 2. Your add-in (which hosted somewhere in https server) to any webservice it uses (directly). And this is it. All communication between webservice to yet another service may be http (best practice anyway to use SSL).

Comment: Please don't forget to include services (as I mention direct services), your add-in will be using, into the manifest, including protocol (example "<AppDomain>https://the.service.uri</AppDomain>").